# if statement on blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There's 2 buttons on my blade like this :

```
<a data-url="{{route('trip.out', ['trip' => $trip->id])}}" data-table-name="#dataTable" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary out">Set - Out</a>
<a data-url="{{route('trip.completed', ['trip' => $trip->id])}}" data-table-name="#dataTable" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary completed">Set - Complete</a>

@push('custom_js')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.out, a.completed').click(function(e) {
    $.redirect($(this).data('url'), {
        _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}',  
    }, 'POST');
})
});
</script>
@endpush
```

the one I want is once I click complete it return finish button,  so i put this :

```
@if ($trip->id == 1)
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Finish</a>;
@endif
```

it doesn't work. Note `out = 0, complete = 1`. status updated on database but it didn't return finish button.

any idea about the problem?

Comment: can you provide more code of your blade file?

Comment: @JayminPanchal updated, anything else?

Comment: every time $trip->id going to be equals to 1?? Your condition should be >=

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be due to this..

```
href="javascript:;"
```

SO change it as

```
@if ($trip->id == 1)
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Finish</a>;
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

When the html have generated with the laravel php, there is no ralations with the blade code.

The blade if is the server code, have nothing todo with you client button click.

If you want to do that, use client js code.